# Using [ComplexType] in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using a property of my own class inside EF Core data model.

```
public class Currency
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Money
{
    public int? CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Money Price = new Money();
}
```

My problem is that when I try to create a migration, EF Core reports a error.

```
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.ModelItemNotFoundException: The entity type 'RentABike.Models.Money' requires a key to be defined.
```

If I declare a key, a separate table for "Money" is created, which is not what I'm looking for.

Is there any way to use ComplexType in EF Core and put it all into a single table?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Support for complex types is currently on the backlog https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/246

Comment: Is this supported yet or am i doing something wrong?  Do you have to declare an object as complex using fluentApi?

Comment: It's finally supported in EF Core 2.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/

You have to use some of fluent API to configure it though, annotations are not supported yet.

Comment: @SergeyKandaurov As of EF Core 2.1, you can now used `[Owned]` attribute to denote owned types.

Answer (score 14):

As an update based on one of your comments above, you now use the `OwnsOne` syntax for this using the Fluent API in your DbContext's `OnModelCreating` function.

```
[ComplexType]
public class Money
{
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public Money Price { get; set; }
}

public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Rate>(entity =>
         {
             entity.OwnsOne(e => e.Currency);
         });
     }
}
```

I'm not actually sure if it makes use of the `ComplexTypeAttribute` or not. But when I generated my migration via Add-Migration, it generated as expected for the old ComplexType documentation this way (i.e. table named `Rate` has column `Price_Amount`).

Answer (score 5):

[Diego Vega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393050/divega) announced [Owned Entities and Table Splitting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/#owned-entities-and-table-splitting), which is supposed to be a different approach and an alternative to complex types.

Can't share my personal impressions because I haven't checked this personally, but [Julie Lerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471760/julie-lerman), [seems to have been satisfied](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/246#issuecomment-317290273)...

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
modelBuilder.Owned<T>:
```

Example:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Owned<Rate>();
     }
}
```

Comment: or you can simply add [Owned] attribute on the entity class itself

Answer (score 1):

As of EF Core 8 in addition to using [Owned Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types) mentioned by other answers the complex types was brought to the framework. From [What's New in EF Core 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#value-objects-using-complex-types) doc:

> Prior to EF8, there was no good way to map the third type of object. [Owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) **can be used, but since owned types are actually entity types, they have semantics based on a key value, even when that key value is hidden**.
>
> EF8 now supports "Complex Types" to cover this third type of object. Complex type objects:
>
> - Are not identified or tracked by key value.
> - Must be defined as part of an entity type.  (In other words, you cannot have a `DbSet` of a complex type.)
> - Can be either .NET [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) or [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).
> - Instances can be shared by multiple properties.

Also check the [current limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#current-limitations) part of the doc.

Answer (score -6):

You can just put [NotMapped] above

```
public class Rate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Money Price = new Money();
}
```

like this.

Comment: This will not put it to the db

Comment: @SergeyKandaurov yess as Money class does not have any primary key value so it is not an entity..and if if it is not entity then it wont be mapped to db ..but u can use it externally but no value of this will be stored in db