# Entity Framework 7 -The entity type 'object' requires a key to be defined

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am getting this error when migrating in EF 7

> Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.ModelItemNotFoundException: The entity type 'object' requires a key to be defined.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This is the dependencies I am using on project.json

- "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
- "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5"

Comment: Maybe start by trying beta 8?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you're using some Data annotations that are not yet supported so you will need to use the Fluent API for configuration.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1913

[Using [ComplexType] in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906950/using-complextype-in-entity-framework-7)