# EF Core Code First Migration requires a primary key for a complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a data class which contains a subclass. They are used in a `DbContext` like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public SubFoo SubFoo { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class SubFoo
{
    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options) {
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

}
```

When trying to create a code-first migration, I get an error

> The entity type 'SubFoo' requires a primary key to be defined

Since my class `SubFoo` is decorated with the attribute `ComplexType` and that the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/data-types/complex-types#delete-a-complex-type) states precisely that *complex types do not have keys*, I am a bit confused.

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416869/complex-type-requires-primary-key?rq=1), I tried to replace the `ComplexType` annotation with an `Owned` attribute but it didn't solve the problem.

Am I misunderstanding how to make use of complex types?

Comment: check this threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416869/complex-type-requires-primary-key; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906950/using-complextype-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: I read both of them before asking, one is even linked to my post. And the other one states that complex types are in the backlog...in 2015! So, I don't really get why those threads are useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line, after a long investigation, ComplexType are not yet supported in EF Core 2.2 when doing a Code First Migration.

Comment: It would be useful to state the version where it's not yet supported, and if you've got a source for that, it would be great to link to it. It might be supported in the future so this answer would become wrong.

Comment: I think I solved this using the `[Owned]` attribute _instead_ of `[ComplexType]` in EF Core 3.1. Has some drawbacks though, as it still doesn't support the `[Required]` attribute in code first (all columns are generated nullable). It may be fixed by https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/21873 on EF Core 5.0