# Entity Framework class type property to snake case

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I want to map `Location` of type `RoomLocation` to

```
Floor -> location_floor,
Building -> location_building,
Room -> location_room
```

`Room.cs`

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public RoomLocation Location { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }  
}

public class RoomLocation
{
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public int Building { get; set; }
    public int Room { get; set; }
}
```

## Database Diagram

[image: Database diagram]

Note: in an older project I forgot to add a `builder.HasKey` and it actually worked I looked at the logs and Entity Framework translated the query to `user_` now because I forgot what exactly happened I can't redo the situation.

I'm using Entity Framework with `Npgsql` with SnakeCaseNamingConvention.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using EF Core (which version?), with the [EFCore.NamingConventions](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions/)? If so, what issue exactly are you hitting?

Comment: @ShayRojansky Version `3.1.1.2` with `EFCore.NamingConventions`, I want `Location` to be mapped with it's properties to snake case, for example `Location.Floor` to `location_floor`.

Comment: Related Github issue: https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions/issues/17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For guidance on similar issues in Entity Framework 6+ you can refer to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60133238/1690217) this solution specifically targets EF-Core

Instead of *Complex Types* as provided in Entity Framework 6+, EF Core has a concept of *[Owned Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)*, this covers most of the use cases that *Complex Types* supported but allows extended usage scenarios including navigation properties and keys.

While no Attribute Notation has yet been implemented for this in EF Core, you can easily use the Fluent API to configure the owned type without any further changes to your classes:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Room>().OwnsOne<RoomLocation>(x => x.Location);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

This is further discussed on SO here: [Using [ComplexType] in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143108/1690217)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem as though anyone has covered this specifically, but the Entity Framework fluent configuration builder does have an option to define custom table and property mappings.

If I had a table in my database called `notifications` with some properties called `notification_title`, `date_created` and `date_modified`. You could then map your properties in your class as follows...

#### Your Model

```cs
public class Notification
{
   public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
   public string NotificationTitle { get; set; }
}
```

#### The fluent configurations

```cs
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>(entity =>
      {
         entity.ToTable("notifications");
         entity.Property(p => p.NotificationTitle).HasColumnName("notification_title");
         entity.Property(p => p.DateCreated).HasColumnName("date_created");
         entity.Property(p => p.DateModified).HasColumnName("date_modified");
      });
   }
}
```

I hope this helps someone. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The following guidance is for *Entity Framework*, **not** *EF Core*. It is still relevant guidance for .Net Framework implementations.

---

The EF feature you are asking about here is facilitated through the use of [Complex Types](https://entityframework.net/complex-type).

> - A ComplexType doesn't have keys and therefore cannot exist independently.
> - It can only exist as properties of entity types or other complex types.
> - It cannot participate in associations and cannot contain navigation properties.
> - Complex type properties cannot be null.
> - Scalar properties of complex objects can be null.

By marking `RoomLocation` as a *complex type*, EF will not create or map to a separate table in the database, but instead will map to fields within the table for the type that contains a property for the complex type.

You can do this with either [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties#configuring-properties-on-a-complex-type) or [Data Annotations](http://Code%20First%20Data%20Annotations) however, as you are using the `KeyAttribute` this example lets continue with Data Annotations (otherwise known as *Attribute* Notation)

So make `RoomLocation` a complex type:

```
[ComplexType]
public class RoomLocation
{
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public int Building { get; set; }
    public int Room { get; set; }
}
```

The default naming convention for the database fields means the following default DB field mapping will be used for this table:

> **NOTE:** this is MS SQL Server Syntax, similar types would be used in *Postgres*, the names of the fields here are important for this discussion.

```
Id UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL,
Title NVarChar(MAX),
Location_Floor INT NOT NULL,
Location_Building INT NOT NULL,
Location_Room INT NOT NULL,
CreationDate DateTime2 NOT NULL
ModificationDate DateTime2 NOT NULL
```

You can use conventions or specific mapping via the Fluent API to map these fields to different named fields.

> **NOTE:** If the casing of your fields is slightly different (Caml, Lower or Upper case) EF will still resolve this mapping and should still work against *Postgres* database fields that are all lower case like your example
>
> > ```
> > item.Location.Floor -> location_floor,
> > item.Location.Building -> location_building,
> > item.Location.Room -> location_room
> > ```

Comment: I have tried that, and I have added `[ComplexType]`, still didn't work, maybe because I'm using entity framework core and when I was searching the internet I did't see entity framework core mention it, only ef 6

Comment: Right, you should have used the entity-framework-core tag instead... Possibly the most important thing to know here.

Comment: your answer is correct but not for my question, the solution for ef core is ```modelBuilder.Entity<Room>().OwnsOne(p => p.Location);```, if you update your answer i will accept it.

Comment: I've posted a separate one, mainly because the advice is still valid for non-core EF